# RFECV is not selecting features

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, rfe

I am using [RFECV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) from scikit learn to select a bunch of features. However, sometimes it does completely ignore the feature selection/

I have set up the following code in a loop:

```
print(f'Selecting features, starting at {number_of_features}')
n_features_to_drop = int(number_of_features  * features_to_drop)

selector = RFECV(estimator=self.model_object, min_features_to_select=number_of_features - n_features_to_drop, step = int(n_features_to_drop / 10), cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)

selector.fit(self.X, self.y)
self.X = selector.transform(self.X)

self.number_of_features = self.X.shape[1]
print(f'Selected {number_of_features} features')
```

This gives the following output:

```
Selecting features, starting at 388
Selected 388 features

Selecting features, starting at 388
Selected 388 features

Selecting features, starting at 388
Selected 388 features

Selecting features, starting at 388
Selected 318 features

Selecting features, starting at 318
Selected 255 features
```

It seems to sometime get stuck on a certain number of features, where the initial number of features is 388 and stays at 388 even after feature selection. How can this behavior be explained?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like it just sometimes thinks keeping all the features is best. Rerunning it may give different results due to the randomized cross-validation splits.  You may inspect the `cv_results_` dictionaries to compare, and create a CV splitter with a fixed `random_state` if you'd like to preserve the same splits (together with a random state in the model object, repeated rerunning shouldn't have an effect except for the differing step sizes).